# How to select object on Fabricjs canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

https://jsfiddle.net/baeyp922/

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    width: 75,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'green',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 3,
    padding: 10
  }));

 canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
    left: 200,
    top: 200,
    radius: 30,
    fill: 'gray',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 3
  }));


$( "#selectrectangle" ).click(function() {
 canvas.setActiveObject(canvas.item(0));
});

$( "#selectsecond" ).click(function() {
 canvas.setActiveObject(canvas.item(1));
});
```

In my mentioned fiddle, While clicking the select rectangle button it select the rectangle shape and while clicking the select second object button it select the second object circle.

I want to highlight/active relevant div while click the object on the canvas. How i do this?

Comment: Where are the div elements?

Comment: @ck_arjun canvas does not have `div` elements. We should use object instead of `div` elements.

Comment: Are you wanting to highlight existing objects on canvas - its not clear what you are asking help for?